# How to use a specfic Tor middle node

Tags: configuration, python, stem

I have a question related to Tor middle node. I already see some of the answers from here. But non of them is recent so I was thinking maybe some imporoment happen in Tor by now. I want to choose a path in a tor such a way that it always use same middle node and exit node. Now i know how to do it with exit node in torrc file but having no idea how to do it with middle node. or if it possible with stem it will be also good. but at the end i want same middle node and exit node. like `MiddleNodes = 192.168.1.1` and `ExitNodes = 72.84.1.7`. All the circuit need to use these two node and start node need to be change for every circuit.

Comment: You can do this with stem, but maybe also try tor's `MiddleNodes` torrc option.

Comment: @Steve how can i do this with stem can you provide some source links to read.

Comment: https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/to_russia_with_love.html#custom-path-selection

Comment: @Steve alreday went through it. but didn't figure a way for `MiddleNodes`

Comment: @Steve it's a bit irrelivent but can you gave me where exitly do i need to put my Nodes

Comment: like `MiddleNodes = 192.168.1.1` and `ExitNode = 72.84.1.7`. All the circuit need to use these two node and start node need to be change for every request